# Solving a system of two exponential equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given that $2^{x+1}-5^y=131$ and $2^{x-4}+5^{y-2}=13$, find the values of $x$ and $y$.

I was set this question in class but I'm not sure how to approach it or look up what I'm supposed to do, any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: If you write $X=2^x$ and $Y=5^y$, the first equation becomes $2X-Y=131$. The second equation becomes a linear equation too, and you can solve a pair of simultaneous linear equations.

Comment: Thank you!! I seem to be remembering my teacher having done that before...

Comment: Assuming an integer solution to the second equation gives an answer trivially (the only available powers of $5$ are $5$ and $1$ and only $5$ works). It is not so difficult to show that there is only one solution. But this is a cheat (though a useful one if you want a quick answer in a test), and if you want a proper solid solution you have to do the work.

Answer (score 1):

Write your System in the form
$$2^{x+1}-5^y=131$$
$$25\cdot 2^{x-4}+5^y=13\cdot 25$$ and add both equations.

Answer (score 0):

## Hint

$$2^{x+1}-5^y=131\Rightarrow2(2^x)-5^y=131$$
$$2^{x-4}+5^{y-2}=13\Rightarrow \frac{2^x}{16}+\frac{5^y}{25}=13$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{cases}
2^{x+1}-5^y = 131 \implies 2(2^x)-5^y = 131
\\ 
\\
2^{x-4}+5^{y-2} = 13 \implies 0.0625(2^x)+0.04(5^y) = 13
\end{cases}
$$

Let $n = 2^x$ and $m = 5^y$.

$$2n-m = 131$$
$$0.0625n+0.04m = 13$$

Just solve the system for $m$ and $n$, followed by plugging in $2^x$ and $5^y$.